# How did Henry Bowers leave the sewers?

Tags: stephen-king, it

In *It*, by Stephen King, Henry Bowers follows the Losers into the sewers in 1958. They defeat It, and escape the sewage after a strange out-of-context orgy.

They never meet Henry again. How does he find his way out of the sewers if even the Losers, guided by Eddie's intuition, had trouble doing so?

Comment: Yeah, the orgy ruined it for me. The book was so good -- great actually; it was *very* descriptive, but then it lost its description in the orgy part (of course), but that part was just... weird, anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think this is ever addressed in the book. As far as I know, the closest thing to a canon answer comes during the Chinese Restaurant scene in the TV series. In a brief discussion of Henry Bowers, Bill says

> I remember when they pulled him out, his hair had turned white.

Presumably, 'they' refers to the authorities (police/fire & rescue/sewer maintenance crews, etc.). So, in the TV series at least, he is rescued.